# Can't add imageViews one by one in layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using this following code but it don't seem to work properly
I am trying to add an image using a button and then showing thumbnail in a specific `relativeLayout`

```
  public void showViewOfReceiptFromSelecting(String uriString)
     {
         byte[] imageData = null;
         try
         {
         InputStream fis = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse((uriString)));
         Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
         imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, 40, 40, false);
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
         imageData = baos.toByteArray();
         ImageView image = new ImageView(this); 
         image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
         image.setId(counterOfReceipts);
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, counterOfReceipts - 1);
         myRelalativelayout.addView(image, rlp);  // a relative Layout i already defined earlier in the code
         counterOfReceipts = counterOfReceipts + 1 ;
         }
         catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         } 
     }
```

Now the problem is, whenever i try to add one more thumbnail, it replaces the old one. Please tell me what to do ...

Best Regards

Comment: can u please put whole code here so i can get better solutions from that

Comment: well, check and please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it gets replaced, because you're not adding a new view to the layout, just replacing the image in it.
Try replacing the RelativeLayout with a LinearLayout, then whenever you want to add a new thumbnail, create a new ImageView, set that ImageView's background to your bitmap, then add it to the LinearLayout.

Don't forget to define your LinearLayout orientation.

Comment: so the code is fine? just change the relative layout type to linear?

Comment: Possibly. RelativeLayout doesn't really care if you're adding a new view in it that will overlap another existing view that was there previously. Maybe your images just overlap each other.